# VLOOKUP from another workbook but mistake is #value

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, inputbox

I take input from user and with this input I use vlookup from another workbook.However I can not get correct value, always #value mistake

```
Option Explicit

Sub SıraNo()
        Dim ResimNo As Long
        Dim Calc As Integer
        Dim p As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        Dim n As Integer
        Dim strVariable As Integer
        Dim wa As Workbook
        Dim twb As Workbook
        Set twb = ThisWorkbook
        Dim j As Integer

Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select
            Do
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                n = n + 1
            Loop

p = 2
For k = 1 To n
            ResimNo = InputBox("Please Enter Resim No")

                         Cells(p, 2).Value = ResimNo
                          strVariable = Left(ResimNo, 4)
                         Cells(p, 3).Value = strVariable

              If strVariable = 5701 Then
               Set wa = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\userpc\Desktop\Gökhan\makro\Teknik Resim Arsiv Listesi_5701.xls")
                     ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$H$1500"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"

                 j = k + 1

     With twb.Sheets("Sheet1")

                 .Cells(j, 4) = Application.VlookUp(.Cells(j, 2).Value2, "Table1", 6, False)

    End With
                    End If
         p = p + 1
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: When I try it , Error box is appeared: CompileError: Variablle is not Defined

Comment: My mistake `Application.VlookUp(.Cells(j, 2).Value2, wa.Sheets(1).Range("Table1"), 6, False)` assuming your Table1 listobject is on the first worksheet of the `wa` workbook

Comment: This time gives #N/A , I tried with different workbook , again same mistake,  Can it be about table which ı defined?

Comment: #N/A indicates the value was not found in the table

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this...

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$H$1500"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
With twb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(j, 4) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(j, 2).Value2, tbl.Range, 6, False)
End With
```